# UIWebView document stays height of tallest content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm loading content into a UIWebView with the following call:

```
NSString *detailHtmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body {background: black;color: white;line-height: 1.4em; font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 30px 0;width: 280px;} p {margin-top: 10px;}</style></head><body id=\"content\">%@</body></html>",[currentWeek objectForKey:@"post_content"]];
[weekDetailController.movie_detail loadHTMLString:detailHtmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Then, after it it finishes loading:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(calculateWebViewSize) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void) calculateWebViewSize {

    [weekDetailController.movie_detail sizeToFit];
    float newHeight = [[weekDetailController.movie_detail stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString :@"document.getElementById(\"content\").offsetHeight"] floatValue];


    newHeight += 300; //height of the other elements
    NSLog(@"Height: %f",newHeight);

    CGRect frame = weekDetailController.movie_detail.frame;

    NSLog(@"Height was: %f",frame.size.height);

    frame.size.height = newHeight;

    weekDetailController.movie_detail.frame = frame;

    [scrollView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];
    [scrollView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
}
```

This works great the first time the view is loaded, but on subsequent views, when different content has been loaded into the UIWebView (using the same call as above), the JavaScript call to get the height returns larger and larger values -- even if the content is smaller, it still returns the height of the largest amount of content that had been in the view at some point.  I've tried loading a blank HTML string into the view to "clear" it, but that doesn't seem to help either.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Uhmm... You are not resetting newHeight in the code above, merely adding 300 on each call...

Comment: whoops - went overboard when removing commented code and removed a line (uncommented) that set newHeight -- original post has been modified

Answer (score 0):

```
[scrollView.scrollView setContentOffset:pt];
[scrollView.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
```

Are you using nested UIScrollViews? It could be that you are only setting the size of the inner scroll view and leaving the outer scroll view to the largest size it's content has been.

Edit:

Also you should just use `[scrollView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];`

Comment: Fixed the CGPointZero item -- thanks for the tip.
No, it's not a nested UIScrollView -- just one with a UIWebView inside it.

The code you pasted was just a copy of what I had above, so unfortunately, nothing solved yet.

Comment: Yeah, I did copy, I meant to point out which part of your code I was referring to. Still, I wonder why you used `scrollView.scrollView`... Anyway, UIWebView is a UIScrollView subclass, so you should still set the contentSize of the outer scroll view. Are you doing it?

Comment: As far as I can tell, UIWebView is not a UIScrollView subclass -- it descends from UIView directly, although it does conform to the UIScrollView delegate.  It definitely doesn't have a contentSize element -- just a frame attribute, which I set above.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, my bad. I haven't really checked the UIWebView class reference until now. Anyway, I can't help you further with just these code. Can you see if there are other relevant lines and post them?

Answer (score 0):

When using nested UIWebViews with Constraints, you need to reset the constraint (e.g. to 1) and reload the webview afterwards:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, coordinator.transitionDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1;
    [self reloadWebView]; //[self.webview reload] doesn't work here, simply load with the given url or given html content
});
```